# java reflection call methods of an already loaded object

Tags: java, reflection, jvm, classloader

How can I call the method of an object that has already been loaded in the JVM using reflection?
I tried

```
Class myClass = Class.forName("myClass");
Method m = com.test.class.getDeclaredMethod("getValue",new Class[] {});
Object result = m.invoke(myClass,null);
```

but i get **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class**.
The method I want to call is void i.e. does not take parameters

**UPDATE**
I have an application that has already loaded a class "A". Another class "B" will be instantiated by a framework. When class "B" is initialized, class "A" has already been loaded in the JVM. I want to call a method from **loaded instance** of class "A" BUT without having a reference to "A" in class "B". In the answers, it seems I must create a new instance of "A" in class "B" but I want access to an already loaded object. If I create a new instance of "A" in "B" why would I want to use reflection? Am I missunderstanding something?

Thanks

Comment: What is the object that has "already been loaded" - and how did you "load" it?

Comment: Reflection is about finding out information about an Object, not finding an Object in memory.  So if you want an instance of Class B to have access to an instance of Class A, you would have to give B a handle to it somehow.

Comment: @user384706, this is just a wild guess, but maybe the method you want to invoke should be a static (class) method, rather than an instance method?  Also, in your update, you seem to be inconsistently using "class" and "instance".  What you're describing doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Answer (score 12):

You're passing the instance of Class as the first parameter to `Method.invoke(..)`, but that's wrong; you want to pass the instance you're interested in.

```
result = m.invoke(myInstance, null);
```

Comment: How do I find myInstance? It has been already been loaded in JVM and have no access to it from this class

Comment: @user: You have to have access to the instance to invoke anything on it - you would need to pass it in or get a reference to it from somewhere.

Comment: If I have reference to the object, why would I need to use reflection? I want to call a method of an object that is already loaded in JVM from another object without having a reference to it

Comment: @user, there are many reasons to use reflection (e.g. iterating through all methods, calling a method when you have the name as a string, etc.).  However, calling an instance method still requires an instance.

Comment: @Matthew: So what I am trying to do is not possible?

Comment: @user I can tell you that there are lots of reasons to use reflection when you have the object in question - however, afaik there is no way to get access to random data in the heap; you would need a way to get a handle on it.

Answer (score 5):

I think you need

```
Class myClass = myObject.GetClass();
Method m = com.test.class.getDeclaredMethod("getValue",new Class[] {});
Object result = m.invoke(myObject,null);
```

Comment: Where do you use myClass ?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
Object result = m.invoke(myClass, null);
```

You should be passing in an *instance* of myClass.  The illegal argument exception is due to invoke getting an argument of type Class instead of type myClass:

```
Object result = m.invoke(myInstance, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I have reference to the object, why would I need to use reflection? I want to call a method of an object that is already loaded in JVM from another object without having a reference to it.

Of course, you need a reference to invoke a method, you can use it like:

```
Object result = m.invoke(myClass.newInstance(),null);
```

But the life period of the instance matters depending on how you create it (normally or by reflection).

Answer (score 0):

The thing about `invoke`, is that you dont have to have the exact instance of the class in question, if the method being called doesn't require any instance variables of the parent class. In fact you can add the `static` modifier to the `Method` and just call invoke with `null, null, Object[]` which is the same as:

```
public void methLab(Method m){
  try{
    m.invoke(m.getDeclaringClass().newInstance(), new Object[0]);
  }catch(IllegalAccessException iae){
   // The method or parent class is declared private or protected
  }catch(IllegalArgumentException iae){
   // unsatisfied input parameters ( in this case, no params were passed) 
  }catch(InstantiationException ie){
   // could be several things  
  }catch(InvocationTargetException it){
   // Method specific, exception chain. call: it.getTargetException().
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and for who know it, is very simple, if you are on the same place class that you want call, do it:

```
Object result = m.invoke(this, null);
```

with **this** you will pass the selfie instance and do not lost your values.